# Simulate HTTP downloads and control bandwidth using Java

Tags: java, http, download, server

I need to implement the server side to download files via HTTP with a limited bandwidth and log each second the downloads.

As for the clients, I will use the `wget` command.

Is it feasible using Java? If so are there any tools that could help me? Thanks.

Comment: this is a possible duplicate of [How can I limit bandwidth in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947621/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-in-java). However it's not simple, if you have full controll over the client (in your case wget, I would go with limiting the download speed directly from the wget client). See this [Throttle the download speed of wget or curl while downloading](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39218/throttle-the-download-speed-of-wget-or-curl-while-downloading)

Comment: I also need to limit the upload speed of the server though

Comment: Ok, I don't use wget in general, but with curl `curl --limit-rate ` it is possible to limit either download and upload. From what i see, also uploading file is much easier with curl than with wget (see this)[http://superuser.com/questions/86043/linux-command-line-tool-for-uploading-files-over-http-as-multipart-form-data]. If you are forced to use java, then go with the proposed solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947621/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-in-java]