# Implement limited bandwith for an URLConnection

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to limit the amount of data transmitted through an `URLConnection` per second. I implemented a wrapper for `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s, as well as for sockets that utilize these streams. Next I created a custom SocketFactory that provides the limited sockets. But now the problem is that I dont know how I can set up an `URLConnection` that uses my `SocketFactory`. Do you have any ideas how to realise that?

One way would be to change the `URLConnetion`s to use my throttled streams but it would be great to access the socket used by the `URLConnection` itself.

Answer (score 0):

hi this is related to another question : [How can I limit bandwidth in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947621/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-in-java)

This solution is easy and works fine for me.

**//SERVER CODE**

```
    Stream in;
long timestamp = System.currentTimeInMillis();
int counter = 0;
int INTERVAL = 1000; // one second
int LIMIT = 1000; // bytes per INTERVAL

...

/**
 * Read one byte with rate limiting
 */
@Override
public int read() {
    if (counter > LIMIT) {
        long now = System.currentTimeInMillis();
        if (timestamp + INTERVAL >= now) {
            Thread.sleep(timestamp + INTERVAL - now);  
        }
        timestamp = now;
        counter = 0;
    }
    int res = in.read();
    if (res >= 0) {
        counter++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

**//CLIENT CODE**

```
 URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
```

source of client code :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: I found that thread as well. It helped me to implement limited streams and sockets. But now i need to know how tu use these sockets in an URLConnection.

Comment: Yes, I am on the client side. I could use the code you provided to create an URLConnection with limited data per timeframe. Still it would be good if i can adress the underlying socket directly somehow. I intended to change the allocated buffer size for sending and receiving on the socket.